# Remote desktop for Linux

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I come from a Windows background and have been using Remote Desktop to view a remote server's desktop on my local machine. Remote desktop is probably the most popular tool for doing this because it's already part of the OS. Is there a similar tool for Windows but for accessing a Linux machine instead?

Comment: seek for tools is off-topic to SO, you should know that with your score.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: FYI: interesting project [Window Switch](http://winswitch.org/), that is somehow related to remote desktop subject.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti I was actually thinking of Linux in general and not some specific version or brand of it. Without knowing, I would assume that any commercial versions of Linux (such as RedHat) would probably include some remote desktop tool beyond what the free versions of Linux offer. But maybe I'm wrong. I'm just starting out with Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try VNC. It works on Mac and Linux. You need to be running the server portion on the Linux host.

Comment: Doing a google search seems to indicate that vnc is a commercial product. Or am I wrong? Is there anything open source?

Comment: There is a lot of different implementations of VNC protocol. Try using tightvnc, or x11vnc server.

Comment: When you say "You need to be running the server portion on the Linux host.", are you saying the Linux doesn't come with any built-in support for being accessed remotely giving the user the Linux desktop on their local machine? Or does that limitation only apply to Windows clients?

Comment: Note that VNC requires that a connection be configured on the server specifically for you.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti So what you're saying is Linux does have some form of built-in support for being accessed remotely (and will provide a desktop view of the server). But all you need is just a client that knows how to use the Linux communications protocol, which I assume is what VNC does? Does that mean that if I am using Linux on my client, I wouldn't need VNC because Linux already has a built-in tool?

Comment: VNC is directly supported on Linux. What you need is a VNC client.

Comment: What?.. VNC support is not builtin, you have to run VNC server manually. x11vnc allows you wrap your currently active X11 session into VNC as long as it runs. tightvnc server will start new X session upon connect. What *may* be builtin is XDMCP protocol, but only if you have XDMCP-compatible display manager (kdm, gdm, maybe some else). Besides, servers usually come without X environment, so there is just nowhere to connect to, as there is no graphics on server. (of course if we're talking about X, situation is different for wayland)

Comment: @AndroidDev There's a server executable and a client executable. I don't know with certainty which Linux distros come with it, but I'd expect it in most. As pointed out by keltar, you have to make sure the server is running before you can access it remotely with the client executable. Years ago, I set up a machine so it would always be running, but I don't remember if explicitly put it in an rc script or via a services configuration. I expect you could find out the recommended solution in the VNC documentation -- it won't be hard.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look  at [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/). According to project description you can even use your native Windows client to access Linux desktop:

> The goal of this project is to provide a fully functional Linux
>   terminal server, capable of accepting connections from rdesktop,
>   freerdp, and Microsoft's own terminal server / remote desktop clients.

Answer (score -1):

try TeamViewer you can download it from
http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx